# Choose impedance value of ferrite beads at any frequency

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, switch-mode-power-supply, high-frequency, ferrite-bead

For example, in my PCB I want to use an SMPS IC but Vout will have noise.

The SMPS works with 2.5 Mhz. What should be the impedance value? How can I choose this value?

Answer (score 1):

> *Smps works with 2.5 Mhz. What should be impedance value. How can I
> chose this value ?*

You probably won't find many ferrite beads that operate effectively at 2.5 MHz. They are usually targeting above 30 MHz. The one below is good from about 30 MHz to 500 MHz for example: -

[image]

In some applications the one above might only be useful between 60 MHz and 200 MHz. It depends entirely on what you are trying to achieve.

$$\boxed{\text{It's a "numbers game"}}$$

[This article](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/ferrite-beads-demystified.html) is very useful if you want to know about ferrite beads.

If you are trying to reduce the ripple voltage from your SMPS it's probably better to use an inductor and capacitor filter.

Comment: I got it. Thank you but it was just example Actually the question I wanted to ask this: For example I will use a ferrite bead. How can I choose Impedance value? like Random? Or is there a rule or formula?

Comment: As I said in my answer: *It depends entirely on what you are trying to achieve.* In other words, you must have a reason or some expectation of a benefit. What is that expectation? I can't read minds!!

Comment: You right Andy Aka. Thankss!!